# Scraping information from many tables on the same page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would need to collect into different arrays some data from this link:

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana

In particular, I would be interested in `Suffisso` and `Significato` columns for each table (`Suffissi aggettivali, Suffissi verbali, Suffissoidi,` and `Suffissi nominali`). 
Please see picture below as an example. `Suffissi aggettivali/Suffissi verbali/ Suffissoidi/and Suffissi nominali` should be the lists' names: each of them should contain `Suffisso` and its related `Significato`. 
Something like this:

`Suffissi_aggettivali={Suffisso -> Significato...}, i.e. {-ale -> '', -ambulo -> camminare, deambulare,`  and so on}.

[image]

I have tried with this:

```
suffix = "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana"
df = pd.read_html(suffix, header=0)
```

But I do not know how to extract that information, so I hope you can help me giving advices on how to go on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_html()` to read all `tables` from `url`.

Then verify the column name and load column  values into list.

**Code**:

```
dfs=pd.read_html("https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana")
for df in dfs:
    if (df.columns[0]=='Suffisso') and (df.columns[1]=='Significato'):
        print(df['Suffisso'].values.tolist())
        print(df['Significato'].values.tolist())
```

**Output**:

```
['-accio[1]', '-aggine[1]', '-aggio[1]', '-aglia[1]', '-aio[1]', '-ame[1]', '-ano', '-anza[1]', '-asco', '-astro[1]', '-ata[1]', '-ato[1]', '-azzo[1]', '-enza[1]', '-eria[1]', '-esco[1]', '-ese', '-età[1]', '-etto[1]', '-ezza[1]', '-fero[1]', '-icciolo[1]', '-iere[1]', '-ino[1]', '-ino[1]', '-iolo', '-ismo[1]', '-ista[1]', '-ità[1]', '.mw-parser-output .chiarimento{background:#ffeaea;color:#444444}.mw-parser-output .chiarimento-apice{color:red}-legio[senza\xa0fonte]', '-mento[1]', '-oide[1]', '-one[1]', '-osi[1]', '-ota[1]', '-oto[2]', '-otto[1]', '-tore[1]', '-tura[senza\xa0fonte]', '-uccio[1]', '-ucolo[1]', '-ume[1]', '-uto[1]', '-uzzo', '-zione[1]']
['peggiorativo', '...', '...', 'valore collettivo e spregiativo', 'agentivo', '...', 'abitante', '...', 'abitante', 'peggiorativo', "deverbale astratto o concreto: indica l'atto espresso dal verbo", 'sali ed esteri derivati da acidi', 'dispregiativo', '...', 'negozio, laboratirio, attività commerciale', 'di relazione, con valore referenziale o spregiativo', 'abitante', '...', 'diminutivo, vezzeggiativo', '...', 'che porta', 'diminutivo', '...', 'agentivo o strumentale', 'diminutivo; abitante', '...', '...', 'agentivo', '...', 'raccogliere', "deverbale astratto o concreto: indica l'atto espresso dal verbo", 'simile a', 'accrescitivo', 'condizione, stato, processo', 'abitante', 'abitante', 'vezzeggiativo', 'agentivo o strumentale', "deverbale astratto o concreto: indica l'atto espresso dal verbo", 'diminutivo affettivo o peggiorativo', 'valutativo', '...', '...', 'diminutivo affettivo o peggiorativo', "deverbale astratto o concreto: indica l'atto espresso dal verbo"]
['-ale[1]', '-ambulo[senza\xa0fonte]', '-ario[1]', '-bile[senza\xa0fonte]', '-ese[1]', '-evole[1]', '-frago[1]', '-fugo[1]', '-ico[1]', '-issimo[1]', '-oso[1]', '-ota[1]', '-oto[2]', '-vago', '-tivo[senza\xa0fonte]', '-torio[senza\xa0fonte]']
['...', 'camminare, deambulare', '...', 'passivo', '...', '...', 'che rompe', 'che fugge, che evita', '...', 'suffisso intensivo', '...portatore di...', 'abitante', 'abitante', 'che desidera, che si muove', '...', '...']
['-are[1]', '-arsi', '-ere[1]', '-ersi', '-arre', '-orre', '-orsi', '-urre', '-ursi', '-ire[1]', '-irsi']
['suffisso dei verbi alla prima coniugazione', 'suffisso dei verbi alla prima coniugazione ed dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare in "-arre" per il riflessivo', 'suffisso dei verbi alla seconda coniugazione', 'suffisso dei verbi alla seconda coniugazione per il riflessivo', 'suffisso dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare "-arre"', 'suffisso dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare "-orre"', 'suffisso dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare in "-orre" per il riflessivo', 'suffisso dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare "-urre"', 'suffisso dei verbi terminanti alla coniugazione irregolare in "-urre" per il riflessivo', 'suffisso dei verbi alla terza coniugazione', 'suffisso dei verbi alla terza coniugazione per il riflessivo']
['-mente[1]', '-oni[1]']
['in modo, in maniera', 'in modo, in maniera']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code would help in working towards a solution. One can keep changing the tables[x] from x = 0 to 4 and then see what information is required and build from there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

response = requests.get('https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffissi_della_lingua_italiana')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll("table", attrs={"class": "wikitable"})

table = tables[0]
rows = table.findAll('tr')
rowData = [[td.findChildren(text=True) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]    

#sample output
rowData[1]
[[u'-accio', u'[1]', u'\n'],
 [u'peggiorativo\n'],
 [u'deriva da un sostantivo\n'],
 [u'cagnaccio', u'\n']]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hello dear SidharthMacherla - many thanks for your answer. I am a BS4 Beginner and i am learning all day long. Can your approach be regarded as a - so called general approach to work with Tables in Wikipedia - as far as i can see  - we can use this like a framework - at least if it comes to tables in wikipedia - to verify this i am trying to apply parts of your answer to other - or let us say similar - tables in Wikipedia. Do you think that this is possible - do  you think that i find such examples and can apply it to these!? i - at least - will give it a try! Many thanks for your idea sharing